# PropertyDescriptor vs PropertyInfo and Export to Excel

Tags: c#

My goal is to export MVC View Model into Excel. I would like to export only columns which have set Display attribute.

I successfully pulled properties to populate column names:

```
        var type = typeof(MyViewModel);
        var propertyMetaData = type.GetProperties()
            .Select(property => property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as DisplayAttribute)
            .Where(attribute => attribute != null)
            .ToList();

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (var prop in propertyMetaData)
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
```

My problem is when I ma trying to populate data:

```
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(MyViewModel));
        foreach (MyViewModel item in lst_VM)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();

            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                if ((prop.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as DisplayAttribute) != null)
                {
                    row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;

                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                }
        }
```

The problem is that the code above is picking all attributes and it returns error that column does not belong to table.

My View Model Looks like below:

> ```
>     [Display(Name = "Application Name")]
>     public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
>     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Make is required.")]
>     public int MakeID { get; set; }
>     [Display(Name = "Make")]
>     public string Make { get; set; }
> ```

and I only want to export these which have set [Display(Name = "")]

Comment: `prop.GetType()` looks like a mistake; that's just going to give you the concrete type of property descriptor implementation; did you mean `prop.PropertyType`? Note: using reflection in one place, and `PropertyDescriptor` in another: is probably going to cause lots of problems. Can you decide on one or the other? They can be **very** different. Also: is `[Display]` on the property? or on the *type* of the property? At the moment, the code suggests the latter - but convention is usually the former.

Comment: Unfortunately I only heard about reflection. I would just make it work. I will appreciate if you could provide me solution.

Comment: well, it is hard to see what you're trying to do from the code; but from your "My View Model", the attributes are on the properties - so you should be looking at `prop.Attributes` (which is a collection of attributes). Just see if it contains a `DisplayAttribute` instance - `prop.Attributes[typeof(DisplayAttribute)] != null` might be what you want

Comment: @MarcGravell I used prop.Attributes[typeof(DisplayAttribute)] != null but still the loop is still hitting properties without Display Name annotation. In debugger I set a bekpoin on prop and I can see that it has only two properties: [0] {__DynamicallyInvokableAttribute} System.Attribute {__DynamicallyInvokableAttribute}
[1] {System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TypeDependencyAttribute} System.Attribute {System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TypeDependencyAttribute}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 10 hours of searching and trying different things I finally found what I need:

```
        foreach (MyViewModel item in lst_Host_VM)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();

            var test = typeof(MyViewModel).GetProperties()
                .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false))
                .Select(p => new
                {
                    PropertyName = p.Name,
                    p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false).Cast<DisplayAttribute>().Single().Name,
                    Value = p.GetValue(item)
                });

            foreach (var itm in test)
            {
                row[itm.Name] = itm.Value;
            }

            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

If you think it could be done in more gentle way, please let me know.